# XAML MenuFlyoutItem and command binding

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to add a 'MenuFlyoutItem' on click to my 'GridView' item.
For this I wrote the following xaml :

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Holding">
    <utils:OpenMenuFlyoutAction />
</core:EventTriggerBehavior>
```

```
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
<MenuFlyout>
    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Uid="LBL_DELETE" 
                    Text="" 
                    Command="{Binding OnDeleteCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
</MenuFlyout>
```

But I do not want the binding happens on the items viewmodel but on my viewmodel class : 'MainViewModel'.
So i modified this line :

```
Command="{Binding OnDeleteCommand, Source={StaticResource MainVM}}"
```

and added this line as resource :

```
<viewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="MainVM"/>
```

It works but now in my editor all my data template definition is underlined and i have this message : Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush' from text ''.

Screenshot here : http://hpics.li/9f17b6e

[EDIT] And if I define text property, error is "Cannot create instance of type 'Average.ViewModel.MainViewModel'"

My code works, but I would remove this warning. 
Does anyone know why I have this message?

Comment: Consider *not* having a empty `MenuFlyoutItem` -- you need to specify the `Text` property.

Comment: Text property is defined by globalization here. 'LBL_DELETE.Text' is defined in my 'Resources.resw'.
But... I tried to add Text property directly, and error is not the same now. Error is "Cannot create instance of type 'Average.ViewModel.MainViewModel'". So, it gives me a track.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After days looking for the answer, I finally fixed the problem ... but without detailed explanation.
Indeed, I updated some of my application package and among others:
"MVVM Light Libraries only"
"Common Service Locator"

It is possible that the error comes from the MVVM Light framework, but now the problem is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to implement command binding with a MenuFlyOutItem.
This implementation leverages Behaviors from Expression Blend 2013.

XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton
                Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=ContactList, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Holding">
            <behaviors:MoveContactBehavior />
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Family" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Friends" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Business" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Class:

```
public class MoveContactBehavior : DependencyObject, IAction
{
    public object Execute(object sender, object parameter)
    {
        var senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
        FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);

        flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);

        return null;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public HomeViewModel()
{
    MoveCommand = new DelegateCommand(MoveContact);
}

public DelegateCommand MoveCommand
{
    get;
    private set;
}

private void MoveContact(object e)
{
    var targetCategory = e as string;
    SelectedCategory.Contacts.Remove(SelectedContact);

    switch(targetCategory)
    {
        case "Family":
            {
                FamilyCategory.Contacts.Add(SelectedContact);
                break;
            }

        case "Friends":
            {
                FriendsCategory.Contacts.Add(SelectedContact);
                break;
            }

        case "Business":
            {
                BusinessCategory.Contacts.Add(SelectedContact);
                break;
            }

        default:
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
    }
}
```

DelegateCommand:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    Func<object, bool> canExecute;
    Action<object> executeAction;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> executeAction)
        : this(executeAction, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> executeAction, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (executeAction == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeAction");
        }
        this.executeAction = executeAction;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        bool result = true;
        Func<object, bool> canExecuteHandler = this.canExecute;
        if (canExecuteHandler != null)
        {
            result = canExecuteHandler(parameter);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = this.CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.executeAction(parameter);
    }
}
```